# When does separate Frechet differentability imply joint Frechet differentiability?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, derivatives, banach-spaces, frechet-derivative

Let $f\colon X \times Y \to Z$ be a mapping between Banach spaces. If I know that $f(\cdot,y)$ and $f(x,\cdot)$ are Frechet differentiable or $C^1$ functions (for fixed $x$ and $y$), what other conditions do I need to ensure that $f$ is Frechet or $C^1$ on the product space? Does continuity of the partial derivatives suffice?

Looking for a reference request or proof.

Comment: I'm late but the existence of the "partial" derivatives will never guarantee the existence of the derivative; you need continuity and then existence of partiales (everywhere on an open set) plus continuity of the partials is _equivalent_ to "total" derivative plus continuity of the total derivative. You can think of a diagram as follows "partials + continuous" $\iff$ "total derivative that is continuous" $\implies$ "total derivative" $\implies$ "partials."

Answer (score 0):

Answer can be found in the final theorem of [these notes](https://math.byu.edu/%7Ebakker/Math346/Lectures/M346Lec03.pdf).